# Iterate through PHP Object to mutate properties if they match a condition

Tags: php

I have an array of objects `[Article(), Article(), Article()]`
Each `Article()` have plenty of `protected properties`.

I want to be able to identify which property is an instance of `PersistentCollection` in order to call `->initialize()` method on it.

[image]

At the end, I want my new array of 3 objects `Array()` on which I called the `initialize()` method only if the property is an instance of `PersistentCollection`

Do you know an efficient way of doing it dynamically ? 
Or is it too expansive in terms of performance and then I should call the methods on the fields I know it is a `PersistentCollection` ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a Doctrine entity?

Comment: yes it is a doctrine entity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `$articles` is your initial array you want to process, something like this should do the trick

```
$closure = function() {
  foreach($this as $fieldValue) {
      if($fieldValue instanceof PersistentCollection) {
          $fieldValue->initialize();
      }
  }
};

foreach ($articles as $article) {
    $initCollections = Closure::bind($closure, $article, get_class($a));
    $initCollections();
}

$initCollections = Closure::bind($closure, $a, get_class($a));
$initCollections();
```

Not sure about perfomance, but don't see any issue with it

Comment: I think this won't work because the properties are protected and looping through an object, like docs says "By default, all visible properties will be used for the iteration." http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.iterations.php

Comment: Well, i tested it, and it worked just fine, iterated even private fields. https://3v4l.org/V0rYQ Look at third argument of Closure::bind - it changes scope of closure http://php.net/manual/en/closure.bind.php